# links of the form steps are not saved

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink

I have a form like this :

```
    <form id="candida-form" action="index.php?gender=<? echo $sex; ?>?step=<? echo $step; ?>" method="get">
    <? if ( $step == -1 ): ?>

    <div style="padding-left: 95px;padding-top: 40px;">
                            <div class="radio-option"><input type="radio" id="male" name="form_sex" value="0" checked /> <label for="male" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images/icon_man.png" /> Male</label></div>
                            <div class="radio-option"><input type="radio" id="female" name="form_sex" value="1" /> <label for="female" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images/icon_woman.png" /> Female</label></div>
                            <div class="radio-option" style="padding-top:9px;"><input type="radio" id="child" name="form_sex" value="2" /> <label for="child" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images/icon_child.png" /> Child</label></div></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="submit-wrapper"><input type="submit" id="nextstep" value="Next Step" /></div>

<? elseif ( $step == 0 ): ?>
                    <div class="form-inner">

                    <? if ( $sex == 0 ): ?>
                        <h2>MALE</h2>
                        <div class="yesno">
                            <div class="section-description">
                                <p>text</p>
                            </div>
                    <? elseif ( $sex == 1 ): ?>
                        <h2>FEMALE</h2>
                        <div class="yesno">
                            <div class="section-description">
                                <p>text</p>
                            </div>
                    <? else: ?>
                        <h2>CHILDREN</h2>
                        <div class="yesno">
                            <div class="section-description">
                                <p>text</p>
                            </div>
                    <? endif; ?>
```

and the variables are those:

```
$step = intval( $_POST[ 'form_post' ] ); // Gather completed step
$sex = intval( $_POST[ 'form_sex' ] ); // Gather gender
```

the idea is that when i click on that input to "next step" the url in the browser is changing like to : `http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0?step=1`

but if i want to put the exact link `http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0?step=1` in a new browser so i can go to the step 1 in of the male gender, it **WON'T**, it will go to the index no to the step, any solutions please? can you help with any idea please ?

Comment: `http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0&step=1`

Comment: your form uses 'get' so $_POST['form_sex'] is never set, use $_GET['form_sex']  PS $step is still not $step+1 for next page

Comment: @Waygood last update is `<form id="candida-form" action="index.php?gender=<? echo $sex; ?>&step=<? echo $step+1; ?>" method="post">` but not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You have the URL wrong with parameters. The correct syntax is:

```
http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0&step=1
```

instead of

```
http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0?step=1
```

ues `&` to string more variables together. The `?` is only used for the first to say that the rest of the URL is variables.

Change this line in your PHP code:

```
<form id="candida-form" action="index.php?gender=<? echo $sex; ?>?step=<? echo $step; ?>" method="get">
```

to

```
<form id="candida-form" action="index.php?gender=<? echo $sex; ?>&step=<? echo $step; ?>" method="get">
```

Edit: Also, change `$step = intval( $_POST[ 'form_post' ] );` to:

```
$step = intval( $_POST[ 'step' ] );
```

You aren't getting your variable back properly.

Comment: since the form is GET, will these parameters get erased? should step be a hidden input instead?

Comment: i tried to put it your way, so the link is like http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0&step=1, but not working :( and another thing i put method="post" not "get" because it's not working with get at all ( the form )

Comment: @Waygood No, it just means that anything else is appended to the `action` of the form.

Comment: @Jimmy No, use the GET instead of post, you already have variables being passed to the URL. Also see the edit.

Comment: @Fluffeh if i put `GET` the url is like this : `index.php?form_post=0&form_sex=0` and the survey doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @Jimmy How can that be, it was a GET and it was sort of working, you change it to a POST, then back to a GET and it stops working?

Comment: @Fluffeh i think it was post all the time and i miss that :( sorry for the confusion, what can i do to correct it ? thanks for the help!

Comment: I generally use `$_REQUEST`, that way I don't have to worry about whether the parameter was passed using GET or POST. There are some caveats if the parameter is passed in both ways, and there's also a php.ini option to include cookies in $_REQUEST (but it's not enabled in the default php.ini).

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is incorrect. You need to use the ampersand characters to separate paramters. Not another question mark:

```
http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0?step=1
```

should be

```
http://xyz.com/survey/index.php?gender=0&step=1
```